# Using the Docker COPY command to only copy files with a certain extension

Tags: angular, docker, npm

I am working on setting up a new build process for one of our Angular applications. To reduce bundle size I have added a build step that includes gzipping all of the files in the dist after a building.

Now the dist folder has all of the regular bundle files and all of the .gz files. I would like to copy only the .gz files to destination directory. Below is a snippet from the docker file where i tried to use the wildcard character but it doesn't seem to work.

```
# generate build
# RUN ng build --prod --output-path=dist
npm run build

############
### prod ###
############

# base image
FROM nginx:1.16.0-alpine

# copy artifact build from the 'build environment' and place it in the nginx servers public directory
COPY --from=build /app/dist/*.gz /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally figured this out and there were a couple of issues with my docker setup. Hopefully these can help someone else in the future.

1. I forgot to set the output path of my build. I needed '`--output-path=dist`' after '`RUN npm run build`'
2. The server also needs the regular files along with the .gz files, so the copy statement should be '`COPY --from=build /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html`'
3. The server needs to know to use .gz files. In the nginx.conf file set '`gzip_static  on;`'